# Sympy deltaintegrate solves separate DiracDelta integrals but not their sum?

Tags: python, sympy

When using deltaintegrate I can easily find the indefinite integrals for two different functions involving DiracDelta functions, such as:

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy.integrals.deltafunctions import deltaintegrate
from sympy import DiracDelta

f1 = DiracDelta(x)
f2 = 2*DiracDelta(x-5)

ans1 = deltaintegrate(f1,x)
ans2 = deltaintegrate(f2,x)

print(ans1,ans2)
```

and that prints `Heaviside(x) 2*Heaviside(x - 5)`.

If I however try to integrate the sum of these two DiracDelta functions as:

```
ans3 =  deltaintegrate(f1+f2,x)
print(ans3)
```

this prints a `None`.

Why does this happen and how can I calculate the sum integral I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `integrate` function rather than `deltaintegrate`:

```
In [5]: integrate(f1 + f2, x)
Out[5]: θ(x) + 2⋅θ(x - 5)
```

The `deltaintegrate` function is used internally by `integrate` which will split the terms before calling `deltaintegrate`. It is not intended that `deltaintegrate` would be used directly by users of SymPy.

Comment: Thanks this worked. So I should avoid using deltaintegrate in my code completely?

Comment: `integrate` is your integration workhorse. If you want to see how and when it calls `deltaintegrate` you can view the source, but most users will not need to call it directly.